# index pattern is not creating in kibana dahboard by logstash using http_poll. error -LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #,

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

i want to call the rest api from logstash and want to send it to elastic search to show data in kibana dashboard.but im gettig error -

```
 [2019-12-23T16:55:24,887][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, => at line 14, column 25 (byte 243) after output {\r\nelasticsearch{\r\nhosts=>{\"localhost:9200\"", :backtrace=>["D:/elasticinstall/logstash-7.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "D:/elasticinstall/logstash-7.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "D:/elasticinstall/logstash-7.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2584:in `map'", "D:/elasticinstall/logstash-7.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:153:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:47:in `initialize'", "D:/elasticinstall/logstash-7.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:26:in `initialize'", "D:/elasticinstall/logstash-7.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "D:/elasticinstall/logstash-7.4.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:326:in `block in converge_state'"]}
    [2019-12-23T16:55:25,982][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
    [2019-12-23T16:55:30,292][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.


    logstash code
    input {
      http_poller {
        urls => {
         urlname =>"http://.."
         }
        }
        request_timeout => 60
        schedule => {every=>"20s"}
        codec => "line"
      }
    }


output {
elasticsearch{
hosts=>{"localhost:9200"}
index =>"logstash_http_poller"
}
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

command from powershell
 logstash -f logstash_http_poller.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => 
    { 
    test1 => "rest api url"
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    # Supports "cron", "every", "at" and "in" schedules by rufus scheduler
    schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC"}
    codec => "json"
    # A hash of request metadata info (timing, response headers, etc.) will be sent here
    metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `elasticsearch` output is wrong, you don't need curly braces around the hosts:

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"                     <-- change this
    index => "logstash_http_poller"
}
```

Comment: i have changed as u said , but still getting same error. any other solution???

Comment: You probably have too many curly braces in the `http_poller` input. Try to make sure they balance out.

Comment: logstash command run successfully without any error.json data from the rest api also im able to see in the powershell screen, but im not able to see any  Index pattern in the Management/Index patterns/Create index pattern text box . what name i should provide in the textbox. can i give any index name in logstash conf file. generally it should show in the management window . but its not showing my index pattern.

Comment: I think this is an unrelated question, you should close this one if it's solved and create a new one.